ASP.NET Core 3.1 site stops working after installing library - Failed to load Core runtime
I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 site that's been working fine. I recently added Stripe.Net to my VS project.
After re-build and publish, I uploaded the the files to my shared IIS hosting. When trying to access the site, I now get the following error message in Chrome:
HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Publish Configuration: Release Target Framework: netcoreapp3.1 Target Runtime: Portable
Stripe.net is a sync/async .NET 4.6.1+ client & portable class library for the Stripe API. It is the official library. The dependencies are:

Project Packages:

Deployment Files:

I use Plesk to access/manage my site and I don't know how to access the Event logs. Any suggestions on how best to troubleshoot this would be helpful. I feel like there might be a missing dependency file but the only new files in the deploy folder are:

Stripe.net.dll
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll

and all these files were copied into the httpdocs folder.


very likely an unhandled exception. 2) no one should use deprecated. .NET Core 3.1


usually a server problem methinks... you might try publishing self-contained to rule out a framework mismatch.

Did you already host the application in IIS before this issue? The Detailed Error Information section of the error page will give you clearer information about your problem.
Anyway, please make sure that you have installed the corresponding runtime from .Net Core 3.1 in the target machine.
Secondly, enabling logging and viewing will allow you to better identify the cause of the problem, which will help resolve the issue. Enable the logging by editing Web.config:
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
            arguments=".\AppCore.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="true"   
            hostingModel="inprocess" 
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
            forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>


the hosting has never changed. site has been working fine for several years. just started having this issue after adding Stripe.Net package via Nuget Package Manager. if I add any packages that are not compatible with .NET Core I usually get little yellow alert icons next to the files, but there are no alert icons. dependencies get published to the output folder and then I FTP the files to the server.

But I think it still cannot be ruled out whether it is a framework compatibility issue. As I mentioned above, have you checked the relevant logs for more information？In addition, you can also try to deploy locally to see if it is a problem with the shared IIS server you mentioned.
